# How to load an existing sheet to current workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel sheet with formulas and text in hundreds of cells.

Is there a way to click a button and add this sheet to the active workbook, in any xls file I have opened?

Some formulas refer to a sheet with a specific name, so when this sheet is present in the workbook, the formulas must work.

The problem is that I cannot find an easy way to convert the already written sheet into a VBA script that will generate it. Or alternatively, find an easy way how to load the written sheet with VBA.

Comment: I'd guess that the best way would be to make a template file from that common worksheet. This would be available to any open workbook from right-clicking a worksheet name tab and choosing Insert. Other than that, a public sub procedure in your personal workbook would be available to 'the active workbook'. However, formula ranges may have to be rewritten.

Comment: I do this for a sheet that marks exams in excel. What I do on that sheet is to do a Find/Replace of the "=" with "xyxy" so all the formulae are effectively dad. Then I move a copy of the sheet into the target file and then do the find/replace of "xyxy" to "=" which means the formulae pick up the "local" names in the target workbook...

Answer (score -1):

```
Workbooks("Book1").Sheets("Sheet1").Copy After:=Workbooks("Book2").Sheets(1)
```

Substitute in your own sheet names

Comment: I'm curious to know why anyone thinks this answer does not answer the question .... "Is there a way to click a button and add this sheet to the active workbook, in any xls file I have opened?"   I've used this extensively copying sheets from one workbook to another